# 'Cannot find module' when using webpack loaders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, webpack, loader

I use custom webpack for my app with Next.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const Webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new Webpack.DefinePlugin([{
          __BROWSER__: "typeof window !== 'undefined'",
          __NETLIFY_BRANCH__: JSON.stringify(process.env.BRANCH),
          __CONFIG__: JSON.stringify({
            GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
            SEGMENT_WRITEKEY: process.env.SEGMENT_WRITEKEY,
          }),
        }])
      )
      config.module.rules.push(
        {
          test: /\.png$/,
          use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
           options: {
             limit: 10000,
             name: 'graphics/[name].[ext]',
           },
         },
       },
       {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'svg-react-loader',
        },
        {
          loader: 'string-replace-loader',
          options: {
            search: ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"',
            replace: '',
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            );
      return config;
  },
};
```

But when I try to add image to my component, my localhost launched, but I receive the error:

```
Cannot find module '../assets/logo.svg'
```

I import my image to the component as usual, and without an image, my app is running. Maybe I should add something to my webpack?
All images set in dir assets.

```
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg'; 

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
render () {
    return (
    <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that path to the SVG file is correct (relative to your component file)? (fwiw, your component file has a typo, `defailt` instead of `default`)

Comment: sorry, it is typo.
yes, the path is correct.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: @robertklep do u need a structure of my project?

Comment: No, don't need the structure, it's not related to that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue (from what I understand from this: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/544) is that Next.js doesn't use Webpack for server side rendering, only for client side, so you can't import an SVG like you do when it's purely a client side React project (i.e. by adding a rule for `.svg` files and run those files through a loader chain).

A possible solution is mentioned [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/982), where the SVG import is not done by a Webpack loader, but by Babel (which *is* used on the server side code in Next.js).

It seems to work for me, like this:

- `npm i babel-plugin-inline-react-svg --save`
- add/merge the following to your Babel config (more info on how to set up a custom Babel configuration [here](https://zeit.co/blog/next2#fully-extensible)):

  ```
   "plugins": [
     "inline-react-svg"
   ]
  ```
- in your component/page, use this (the name of the variable, `LogoSVG`, is important and shouldn't be changed):

  ```
  import LogoSVG from '../assets/logo.svg';
  ```
- and use it as a React component:

  ```
  return <LogoSVG alt="logo" />
  ```

Comment: thanks, I edit this part, but error about module is still here :(

Comment: what if I will use a lot of images in Component?
I cannot be all like React components.

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner in that case, you should probably consider making those images static resources (https://github.com/zeit/next.js#static-file-serving-eg-images)

Comment: one other thing. I use for my project Glamor and have file _document.js for this. When I add additional pluging to Babel, console shows me that error  `Unexpected token: return { ...page, ...styles }`
`...` is not good for it.
Maybe you know how can I avoid it?

Comment: Which presets are defined in your Babel config? It should (at least) contain `next/babel`

Comment: Can I ask you something else? I try to add font, and receive the same:
`Cannot find module '../static/fonts/gotham-fontface.css'`

I add to webpack:
`{
          test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },{
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        },`

Comment: @ValeriaShpiner that's exactly the same issue (Webpack loader support in Next.js is very limited). You should try and see if there's a similar plugin for Babel, like `inline-react-svg`, that may be used to inline CSS. Or use static CSS, instead of importing it into your components (which isn't a bad solution either, IMO).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150334/discussion-between-valeria-shpiner-and-robertklep).